# How can I format WPFToolkit.DataGridTextColumn by full date?

Tags: wpf, datetime, sorting, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have searched and tried many methods to format a Date of Birth column by not only Month and Day, but also taking into account the Year.

I can't believe this is so difficult to do.

I have created several type converters which converted a string "MM/dd/yyyy" to a DateTime, tried converting to a string without the '/' characters, and converted to a string with the year first: "yyy/MM/dd".  The last one actually worked, but I can't use it since the date must be displayed in "MM/dd/yyyy" format.

I can't find a way to easily implement a custon sort (ICoparable) on that single column.

I also searched Stack Overflow and other sites, and I am very surprised that I could not find an answer.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the bit of code I have:

```
<dg:DataGrid Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Members}"
  Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowMemberResults, Converter={StaticResource boolTovisConverter}}"
  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  Name="MemberGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMemberItem}" MaxHeight="200">
  <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Member ID" Binding="{Binding Path=MemberID}" Width="100"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="100"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Middle" Binding="{Binding Path=MiddleInitial}" Width="50"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="100"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Suffix" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="50"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="DOB" Binding="{Binding Path=DOB, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" Width="80"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Relationship" Binding="{Binding Path=Relationship}" Width="100"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Name" Binding="{Binding Path=GroupName}" Width="225"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Address " Binding="{Binding Path=Addr1}" Width="180"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding Path=City}" Width="120"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="State" Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Width="45"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Zip" Binding="{Binding Path=Zip}" Width="50"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="SSN" Binding="{Binding Path=SSN}" Width="100"/>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Family Link ID" Binding="{Binding Path=FamilyLinkID}" Width="100"/>
  </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind the data using a [StringFormatter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/07/07/customize-format-of-datetime-string-in-wpf-and-winform-data-binding.aspx):

```
 <wpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Your Header" Binding="{Binding TheDate,StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm\}}" />
```

Comment: The deal is that the database returns it as a string since it needs to be placed in a Dictionary<string, string> for cache purposes (not my code). I tried to convert it to a DateTime hoping sort would use the DateTime and not the string property. All I did was create another property as DateTime and bind it to that.

So in reality, I did not give enough information :-(

Comment: Ah, that was next on my list, but you beat me to it. No need for sad faces, it's fixed now, so happy faces: :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText,StringFormat={}\{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm tt\}}" />
```

and also take a look for more binding stringformat options at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: could you just share your code snipt for which you are looking the answers.